# Sitecore Import language file feature - does it create language versions?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Can anyone tell me what happens if I export a language file, rename all the language nodes to a different language (e.g. from en-US to en-GB) and then import it?

Are new language versions of the relevant items created? Or is content only imported if the language version exists?

Edit: corrected typo in title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the new language versions are created. However, the language item itself is not created (if it doesn't exist before). Hence, if you run a Database Clenup afterwards, for instance, it will remove these item versions.